# iOS - get self process start time after the fact

Tags: ios, plugins, process, sandbox

I am writing a plugin bundle for iOS applications (I will spare you the details). When my bundle is loaded, which isn't necessarily when the main application bundle loads, I would like to get the "Uptime" of the process in seconds (or higher) resolution.

I know in other OS's (Unix / Linux / Android) I could enumerate the `kinfo_proc`s or use the `/proc/self/stat` approach, but I wasn't able to achieve my goal from inside the iOS Application sandbox.

Is there some standard syscall / `NSProcessInfo` property I can use for that?

The purpose of this is mostly for debugging, but it could turn into a feature down the road. Therefore an approach that is eligible for AppStore is preferred, but not mandatory.

Comment: what do you mean by `I will save you the details` ? Is this `typo` ?

Comment: Sorry, meant to write "spare you the details"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]` to get the PID, and then `sysctl` to get the unix start time.

I actually found another answer on SO for the same question, just on OSX: [Is there any way to get the application's run time in Cocoa for OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483407/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-applications-run-time-in-cocoa-for-os-x)

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

pid_t pid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier];
int mib[4] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, pid };
struct kinfo_proc proc;
size_t size = sizeof(proc);
sysctl(mib, 4, &proc, &size, NULL, 0);

NSDate *startTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:proc.kp_proc.p_starttime.tv_sec];
NSLog(@"Process start time for PID:%d is %@", pid, startTime);
```

I'm not sure about App Store eligibility, but this worked for me both in the simulator and on device. Try submitting and let us know?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Works perfect from Xcode, thanks! I don't plan to submit it soon, but when I do I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @PhilippHofmann eventually I never tried to get it into the AppStore...